# descontar valor en diferentes registros

Tags: java, mysql

Buenos Dias por favor si me pueden guiar.tengo una tabla llamada `pago` donde esta el cliente que debe y otra `detalle` donde estan los pagos que debe hacer el cliente.

Quisiara saber si el cliente tiene en la tabla `detalle` 4 pagos por valor de 500.000 y abona 300.000 como hago para que vaya a cada pago individual y vaya descontando de cada pago de detalle hasta que se acabe el valor que abono.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si entendí bien tu pregunta, si ya se sabe cuántos pagos debe realizar el cliente, lo mejor sería usar una tabla adicional para registrar cada `abono` (enlazado a su `detalle`). Adicionalmente, por cada registro puedes ir descontando el monto abonado de la deuda en `detalle` o, cuando hagas la consulta hacer la operación de resta.

Comment: te agradezco mucho soy muy novato , voy a poner un ejm tengo un cliente con dos deudas una por 300 y otra por 500 y el cliente me abona 400 quiero que el primer pago coja los 300 y lo deje en cero y continue al siguiente y reste a 400 los 100 que quedan y lo deje en 100 que es el saldo que queda ya tengo el select y  el while donde toma los dos registros pero no logro hacer el descuento registro por registro

Comment: No deberías poner en 0 la "deuda 1" ni restar la diferencia en "deuda 2", cómo te mencioné anteriormente deberías agregar un registro por cada abono que haga el cliente y calcularlo. Se me ocurre lo siguiente: agregar un campo boolean para saber si esa deuda está pagada o no y, por cada pago q se haga, tras guardarlo ver si el monto es mayor a la primera deuda, sí lo es marcarlo como true en el campo recién creado. La diferencia queda para la segunda deuda pero como aún no la completa no se cambia nada. Para un reporte tendrías que sumar las deudas y los abonos y mostrar la diferencia.